# Issues with POCO Entities

Tags: entity-framework, poco, t4

I am using POCO entities in my application.

So i have three files:

```
DBModel1.edmx
DBModel1.Context.tt
DBModel1.tt
```

Under **DBModel1.tt**, I have all **POCO Entities**.

Now my **DB** is copied to a new Server, wherein **1** new **table** has been **Added** to the database.

So I have to **add** one more **POCO entity** for **new table**.

Since now it's a complete **new DB**, I would have to create a **new EDMX** and **tt** files.

Is there anyway :

- to make context.tt file point to new EDMX
- to add new POCO Entities in existing tt file

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to support both old and new database ? Otherwise why not to use the old EDMX for the new database?

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358699/adding-poco-entities

Answer (score 0):

To point .tt file to another EDMX file you just need to open the file and change its declared `inputFile` filed to another path.